# Python pandas to_sql populates all rows with NA

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to Python and want to upload a Panda's data frame  into a table on Snowflake database. The desired behavior is to replace an existing table if it already exists. Here's my code to do so:

```
#Import the required modules and packages
from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import pandas
from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import pd_writer
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import os 

#import the data from a local csv
my_data_frame= pandas.read_csv("my_data_frame.csv" , sep=',' , low_memory=False)

#Connect to Snowflake
engine = create_engine(URL(
                        account = 'my_snowflake_account',
                        user = 'my_snowflake_id',
                        password = 'my_snowflake_password',
                        database = 'my_database',
                        schema = 'my_schema',
                        warehouse = 'my_warehouse',
                        role='my_role',
                      ))
connection = engine.connect()

#Push my local data frame into a new table
my_data_frame.to_sql('new_table_name_on_Snowflake', engine, 
                    index=False, method=pd_writer, if_exists='replace')
```

The code runs. It creates a table and assignes the correct table names in it. However all rows for all columns are populated with NA. I suspect it has to do with data types. How may I resolve this?

Please note that I specify the `method=pd_writer` as suggested in Snowflakes' documentation:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#pd_writer

When inspecting the my_data_fame with `my_data_frame.dtypes` it returns:

```
column1             object
column2             int64
column3             object
column4             object
column5             object
column6             object
column7             int64
column8             int64
```

Comment: Can you share the definition of the dataframe?  As you said, it might be related to datatypes.

Comment: what do you by definition @MikeWalton? :)

Comment: `my_data_frame.dtypes` would be helpful.

Comment: @MikeWalton thanks I've edited the post

Comment: based on that df definition, what was the DDL for the table that Snowflake created?  Also, I'm curious if you've tried using the write_pandas() function instead of the to_sql() function and whether that gives you the same results.

Comment: @MikeWalton `write_pandas()` alone doesn't work because the table needs to exist so it can populate the rows there. So it seems that `to_sql()` creates a new or replaces the existing table and then calls internally `write_pandas()` via the `method=pd_writer` parameter to write the rows. Perhaps do I need to specify `dtype` inside `to_sql()`?

Comment: I was headed in this direction, which is why I asked for the DDL of the table, but glad you had answered it previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For no rational reason, upper casing the column names solves the problem. So Insert the following before calling `to_sql`

```
my_data_frame.columns = map(str.upper, my_data_frame.columns)
```